# TikZ: Perpendicular bisector of a line

Tags: tikz-pgf

Given two coordinates A and B, I'd like to draw the perpendicular bisector (of any length) of the line joining A and B.

I am not given any extra information, and A and B can be any two coordinates (i.e. the line can have any slope).

Can this be done in TikZ?

Comment: Isn't there a tutorial example (the Euclid one) in the `pgfmanual` document for this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, with the `calc` library. See section 13.5.4
*The Syntax of Distance Modifiers* in the manual.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,1.2);

\draw (A) -- (B) coordinate[midway] (M);
\draw [blue,thick] ($(M)!0.5cm!270:(A)$) -- ($(M)!0.5cm!90:(A)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I knew I had to use the "! !" notation, but I couldn't figure out how. This makes it perfectly clear.

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility is the `turn` option. See section "13.4.2 Rotational Relative Coordinates" in the manual.

```
\documentclass[margin=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path
    (0,0)coordinate(A)
    -- coordinate(M)
    (3,1.2)coordinate(B)
  ;
  \path
    (A)
    -- (M)
    -- ([turn]90:.5)coordinate(l1)
    -- ([turn]180:1)coordinate(l2)
  ;
  \draw (A) -- (B);
  \draw[orange] (l1) -- (l2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]